# What is a 'plated harness'?

Tags: obscure-terms

I came across this paragraph reading [John Adams by David McCullough](https://books.google.fr/books?id=nZByZiwzD24C&pg=PT312&lpg=PT312&dq=Of%20London,%20he(Jefferson)%20thought%20only%20the%20shops%20worthy%20of%20attention,%20and%20devoted%20ample%20time%20to%20them,%20spending%20lavishly%20on%20shoes,%20boots,%20a%20flintlock%20rifle,%20a%20reading%20lamp,%20plated%20harness%20and%20stirrups,%20and%20a%20set%20of%20chessmen&source=bl&ots=YcUpNFC6g2&sig=560tOFAfueafwjNIDcDyBbFQA6A&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Of%20London%2C%20he(Jefferson)%20thought%20only%20the%20shops%20worthy%20of%20attention%2C%20and%20devoted%20ample%20time%20to%20them%2C%20spending%20lavishly%20on%20shoes%2C%20boots%2C%20a%20flintlock%20rifle%2C%20a%20reading%20lamp%2C%20plated%20harness%20and%20stirrups%2C%20and%20a%20set%20of%20chessmen&f=false),

> Of London, he(Jefferson) thought only the shops worthy of attention, and devoted ample time to them, spending lavishly on shoes, boots, a flintlock rifle, a reading lamp, ***plated harness*** and stirrups, and a set of chessmen.

According to Dictionary.com, plate uses as verb means "to coat (metal) with a thin film of gold, silver, nickel, etc., by mechanical or chemical means". So does "plated harness" here mean 'metal-coated harness"?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plate) correctly indicates that metal-on-metal is not mandatory.

Comment: "Plat" is an alternative spelling of "plait," so are we sure this isn't "plaited" (plated)? Harnesses are leather, typically.

Comment: And from context, the harness and stirrups are problably sliver- or gold-plated.

Answer (score 2):

Yorik is correct. McCullough uses *plated* in the sense of *[plaited](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=gcide&Query=plait)*. Harness is made of leather and must be supple. Nobody would cover it with metal plates either for decorative or for military purposes.